# Node js: POST/GET method isn't working when called by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

This is the AJAX function:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("div").click( function() {
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'/activity',
      data:"ok",
      success:function(data) {
        window.alert("Entered AJAX");
      }
    })
  });
});
```

This is my POST:

```
app.post("/activity", urlencodedParser, function(req,res) {
  console.log("Entered POST");
  res.redirect('/activity/test');
  res.end();
});
```

And finally that is my GET:

```
app.get('/activity/test', function(req,res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
  console.log("Entered GET");
});
```

So I get the "Entered GET" message in console, but the page is still the initial one and I don't have any "hello world" message.

On the other hand, when I give the same POST request from another form, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The page your browser displays won't change because of this ajax call. The "hello world" string your webserver returns should be inside the data passed to your success callback.

If you want your browser to display the '/activity/test' page after completing the post request try to add this to your success callback:

```
window.location.href = 'www.yourpage.com/activity/test';
```

Comment: Yes, but after the redirect i want to handle a GET request. And if I add that line, i cannot handle a GET request

Comment: Yes you can. If you add that line then your browser will send a GET request which your server can handle.

Comment: No, i cannot handle GET request. I get: "The address wasn’t understood"

Comment: Worked with window.location.replace("./activity/o")

Answer (score -1):

I think `hello world` message will be in the response of the sent AJAX request. You can redirect to a separate page from the UI if needed.